# Understanding CoreBluetooth scanning and connection flow

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I'm experimenting with `CoreBluetooth` and I stumbled across something that I don't understand.
While scanning for nearby bluetooth device, when I log the results I don't quit understand the output, for example - Some of the devices that were found:

```
discovered peripheral =  <CBPeripheral: 0x281b7c140, identifier = FC3098A3-426F-F1CF-C053-1D62E3EDE473, name = (null), state = disconnected>
discovered peripheral =  <CBPeripheral: 0x281b78000, identifier = 3313CAC4-3D8F-C225-4ABB-73390CCA1DC3, name = SL-1000S_BLE(ATT), state = disconnected>
discovered peripheral =  <CBPeripheral: 0x281b640a0, identifier = D509D6C8-F5C4-E2E5-9387-B6294BCA5396, name = (null), state = disconnected>
discovered peripheral =  <CBPeripheral: 0x281b78140, identifier = A2DC3485-F341-4AAB-6B09-8816FFACA15A, name = (null), state = disconnected>
discovered peripheral =  <CBPeripheral: 0x281b7c280, identifier = 89069574-F6F9-0637-1723-FEB36C3EE2B8, name = (null), state = disconnected>
discovered peripheral =  <CBPeripheral: 0x281b78280, identifier = 792BCEC8-471F-2327-6AD1-33EC57F2A758, name = (null), state = disconnected>
discovered peripheral =  <CBPeripheral: 0x281b783c0, identifier = B7A4C076-D761-5646-0E66-DA832A9061BB, name = Amazfit Band 5, state = disconnected>
discovered peripheral =  <CBPeripheral: 0x281b7c3c0, identifier = 759BD68B-0E48-F0D6-1C08-43F4D2DA528A, name = (null), state = disconnected>
```

Why some of the devices, have a name, and some have null as a name?

Another thing, I have an Android phone with Bluetooth on but I don't see it in the result logs.
The only way I can see the Android device is if I manually go to iPhone's Bluetooth settings find the Android device in the scan **results*** and connect to it manually. After connecting manually I see that following log:

```
discovered peripheral =  <CBPeripheral: 0x281b790e0, identifier = 7E34D617-731F-616E-8C89-5729870CDD5E, name = Edward's Galaxy S9+, state = disconnected>
```

Now, after connecting manually why is the state of the connection says `disconnected` even though if I go to settings I see that it says that it is connected?

One more thing, why while scanning for the devices in the Bluetooth settings I do see the device, but the results of the scans of my app it doesn't appear?

Here's the code snippet:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    
    switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
            print("poweredOn")
            self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:false])
            break
        @unknown default:
            print("default")
            break
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    if(!peripheralsArray.contains(where: { $0.identifier == peripheral.identifier})) {
        print("discovered peripheral = ", peripheral)
        peripheralsArray.append(peripheral)
    }
 }
```

Comment: The avdvertisement data of a device (ie what's yelling a BLE device: "I'm here, my name is ZzZ and I reveal that I have some services with UUID AaA...) might be quite long and is sent piece by piece. Because you just received the "basic piece" without the name, you'll get the name later. I'd use also `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` to `true` in your case. The state is inside your app if I recall. Meaning that if your app didn't connected by itself, it's disconnected. You won't know if another app is.

Comment: @Larme, what do you mean by `you'll get the name later`? I get the name only after I connect manually from settings.

Comment: Set true to the duplicateKey allowed, and scan. In didDiscover, print the discovered peripheral, even if present in your `peripheralsArray`. print also the `advertisementData`. The device should appear multiple times, and with more infos than the first time.

Comment: @Larme, I tried what you've suggested, but I see the same results in the logs, nothing changes. I'm logging the `peripheral` data and the `advertisementData` on each update of `didDiscover` method, but I don't get new information.